# How to force browser to use specific adobe reader version

Tags: php, pdf, adobe, adobe-reader

I am writing a php web application which needs to open pdf files in the browser with Adobe Reader. Some people have multiple versions of the Adobe Reader plugin installed to their browsers. Adobe Reader 10.1.3.23 seems to be causing problems with opening pdfs for some people, Reader 9.5 seems to still work fine though. Is there a way to progarmatically force a clients browser to use an older version of the Adobe Reader plugin if the client has multiple versions of the Adobe plugin installed on their browser?

Comment: Can several versions of Reader be installed at once?

Comment: I don't think so but after the Adobe Reader/Acrobat 10.1.3.23 update, it looks like Firefox will use multiple versions at the same time. I noticed this when I looked at my Firefox plugins list. It had Acrobat 9.5 and Acrobat 10 enabled. After disabling version 10, my pdfs worked again. So it seems like Adobe Reader/Acrobat 10.1.3.23 is the culprit here.

Comment: What is the problem specifically, and have you reported it to Adobe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You don't have this kind of control over a user's browser. And that's a good thing because it could be used to exploit Adobe Reader bugs which seem to litter previous versions of the software.

Comment: Well Adobe's recent update, Reader 10.1.3.23, seems to be causing a lot of problems for people trying to view pdf's. This isn't happening just on my website but other sites as well. I thought I could somehow force clients browsers to use an older version of Adobe Reader since version 9.5 worked fine. Is there any solution to this or do we all just have to wait for another update from Adobe?

Comment: Unfortunately this would require a fix from Adobe